# Length of 2 line parts

Tags: trigonometry

Given a line $AB$ and a point $C$ on that line,
how would I prove that $|AB| = |AC| + |CB|$

It may look obvious, but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: @MatthewConroy For example, I tried to use the triangle inequality, but the proof I found was based on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameterize the line segment as $x=t, y = mt + b.$

Pick your favorite values of $t_1, t_2$ for your points $A$ and $B$:

$$A = (t_1, mt_1 + b), B = (t_2, mt_2 + b).$$

Let's say $t_1 < t_2.$  Then take any $t$ such that $t_1 < t < t_2$ and let that define $C$.  Then

$$|AB|^2 = (t_2 - t_1)^2 + (mt_2 - mt_1)^2,$$
$$|AC|^2 = (t - t_1)^2 + (mt - mt_1)^2,$$
$$|CB|^2 = (t_2 - t)^2 + (mt_2 - mt)^2.$$

Multiplying out you'll find that $|AB|^2 = (|AC| + |CB|)^2$ and the desired result quickly follows.

Answer (score 1):

Look at $\angle ACB$ and $\triangle ABC$ and the Law of Cosines would say that

$$|AB|^2 = |AC|^2 + |CB|^2 - 2 |AC| |CB| \cos \theta.$$

As $\theta \to \pi,$

$$|AB|^2 \to |AC|^2 + |CB|^2 + 2 |AC| |CB| = (|AC| + |CB|)^2,$$

or

$$|AB| = |AC| + |CB|.$$